# How to use Task.WhenAll() for multiple Lists of different return types?

Tags: c#, generics, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I have two sets of Tasks, each with different result type:

```
IEnumerable<Task<T1>> set1 = GetTasksOfT1();
IEnumerable<Task<T2>> set2 = GetTasksOfT2();
```

Now I would like to await both sets in one line, but I had to project set1 with cast:

```
 await Task.WhenAll(set1.Select(p => p as Task).Concat(set2));
```

That's because I get this error if I don't use casting:

```
IEnumerable<Task<T1>>' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' 
and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Concat<Task<T2>>(IQueryable<Task<T2>>, IEnumerable<Task<T2>>)' 
requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<Task<T2>>'
```

Which is obvious.

So is there a way to use a single WhenAll() without casting?

Edit:
The return types T1 and T2 **are** important - I consume them after the tasks are awaited:

```
//After await Task.WhenAll(...):
var t1Results = await set1; // all set1 Tasks are completed by now 
var t2Results = await set2; // same
DoSomethingWithResults(t1Results, t2Results);
```

Comment: Do both `T1` and `T2` adhere to a common interface?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse please see my edit. However, using the blocking method `Task.WaitAll()` is quite a bad advice.

Comment: @Shay__ - you're right, that was bad advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the compiler just complains about type inference failure. You can help it with that:

```
IEnumerable<Task<int>> set1 = null;
IEnumerable<Task<string>> set2 = null;

set1.Concat((IEnumerable<Task>)set2); //#1
((IEnumerable<Task>)set1).Concat(set2); //#2
set1.Concat<Task>(set2); //#3
```

There are many other ways to provide the type information. This works because `IEnumerable` is covariant. This will call `Enumerable.Concat<Task>(IEnumerable<Task>, IEnumerable<Task>)`.

Comment: Great answer! I'll go with #3 :)

Answer (score 2):

If both methods, `GetTasksOfT1` and `GetTasksOfT2` wouldn't return `Task<T>` but `Task`, you woulnd't have any problem.

So I suggest either refactor these method to return a sequence of Task objects, `IEnumerable<Task>` or pickup the Kote's solution.

Comment: No, I need to consume those results once the tasks are completed.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the results of both sets of `Task`s, then it might be simpler to not wait for the all the lists.

I imagine your code (using usr's suggestion) would look like this:

```
IEnumerable<Task<T1>> set1 = GetTasksOfT1();
IEnumerable<Task<T2>> set2 = GetTasksOfT2();

await Task.WhenAll(set1.Concat<Task>(set2));

var t1Results = await Task.WhenAll(set1);
var t2Results = await Task.WhenAll(set2);
```

Bu here, the combined `await` doesn't really serve any purpose. If you remove it, both result variables will still be initialized correctly, because they have their own `await`s.

Answer (score 0):

Although being debatable if creating an array is better than concatenating two enumerables, you could leave the concatenation out of the equation:

```
await Task.WhenAll(set1, set2);
```

But, since what you need the is the result of evaluation of each sequence of tasks, I wouldn't bother to await them all as a single set:

```
DoSomethingWithResults(await set1, await set2);
```